# How do I return text between two found parts using sed?

Tags: macos, sed

I'm trying to just return the actual title between the two html tags:

```
echo "<title>This is some text</title>" | sed -n 's/>\(.*\)</\1/p'
```

I thought this would return just the title, but it's returning this instead:

```
<titleThis is some text/title>
```

Help?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want to strip everything before and after your title in the substitution, rather than just the brackets.

```
echo "<title>This is some text</title>" | sed -n 's/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/p'
```

Comment: How do I only return the first instance?

    <title>This is some text</title> blah blah blah <title>This is some different text</title>... and only return "This is some text"?

Answer (score 0):

If `sed` is not a strict requirement, there are more readable options, such as this `grep`:

```
$ echo "<title>This is some text</title>" | grep -oP '(?<=<title>).*(?=</title>)'
This is some text
```

It uses [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

If for some reason `-P` option doesn't work, you can use `perl` to use similar syntax:

```
$ echo "<title>This is some text</title>" \
| perl -nle 'print $& if m{(?<=<title>).*(?=</title>)}'
This is some text
```